# How to run a code block after the view loads

Tags: javafx, fxml

When using an fxml file and controller, it is possible to have an initialize method, which runs before the view loads. Similarly, is there a way to run a block of code after the view loads?
To be more specific, I have a `Rectangle` in the fxml file. I want to call the `Rectangle`'s `setFill()` , method, from the controller, after the view loads and pass a `LinearGradient` instance. `LinearGradient` has properties without setters and doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so I don't think the fill property can be assigned in the fxml file.
I tried putting this code in the constructor of the controller but that results in an error. If possible, I would also like to know what procedure takes place with regards to the controller class when `FXMLLoader` loads an fxml file (when is a constructor called).

Please take a look at this sample code if necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<Pane fx:controller="sample.RectController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Rectangle fx:id="rect" height="200.0" width="200.0" />
</Pane>
```

```java
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class RectController{
    @FXML Rectangle rect;
    {
        //code i would like to run but currently results in an error
        rect.setFill(new LinearGradient(
            0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, 
                new Stop(0, Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(1, Color.RED)
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: "_When using an fxml file and controller, it is possible to have an initialize method, which runs before the view loads_" – I believe there's a misunderstanding. The initialize method is invoked after, not before, the FXML has been fully loaded and the FXML-related fields have been injected into the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your controller to implement a no-arg `initialize()` method annotated with `@FXML` (The old way was to implement `javafx.fxml.Initializable` but as you can see from the [docs for that method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html), you don't need the interface anymore.)

You can't do it in the controller's constructor because the fields haven't been injected yet by the FXMLLoader.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I was under the impression that the `initialize()` method is called before the root element is processed, but this cleared up my problem.